# Can not execute while statement using Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have one issue.I can not execute the query present inside while loop when DB has only one row using Mysql and PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
$sqlchk=mysqli_query($con,"select * from db_send_evoucher_code where receiver='".$userid."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlchk) >0){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlchk)){
        $vCode=$row['voucher_code'];
          echo $vCode;exit;
   }
}
```

here i am not getting the echo value.i can here mention that i have only one row in `db_send_evoucher_code` table.Please help me.

Comment: You have an `exit` in your while loop, this means it will only run until it reaches the exit which in this case is right after you echo `$vcode`

Comment: it is not displaying any `$vcode` value first.at least one value should display.